# How to properly perform host or dig command in python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, network-programming, blacklist

I want to process host or dig commands using python to check if a domain is blacklisted. I use these

```
surbl_result = os.system(host_str + ".multi.surbl.org")
#this works like performing a terminal command which is host johnnydeppsource.com.multi.surbl.org
```

It returns a response which is an integer 0 (which means it is listed in the blacklist) or 256(it is not listed)

```
if surbl_result == 0: #blacklisted in surbl
    black_list = True
```

but sometimes, the host command fails and gives a serve fail response

```
Host johnnydeppsource.com.multi.surbl.org not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

And this returns a zero value permitting it to add the new domain even if it is blacklisted.. Are there other ways to perform this kind of thing? This is contained in my django 1.6 application. Any leads will help..

Comment: You should use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html). This probably doesn't solve your problem entirely but you can see that [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) is not the way to go to call system commands.

Comment: Thanks for responding @msvalkon.. Unfortunately, I used that too and it still has problems in response.. So I reverted it back to os.system coz it works for surbl and spamhaus blacklists

Answer (score 1):

os.system(command) returns the exit_status after Executing the command (a string) in a subshell.

Better to use in the below manner:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
subproc = Popen(host_str + ".multi.surbl.org", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
output, errorCode = subproc.communicate()
if errorCode == None:
    black_list = True
```

Comment: Thanks kvivek.. It still returns a None on errorcode even if the response has servfail.. but this gave me the capability to print the output.. thanks!